# Vue - Single File Component not rendering

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a small app, which will include multiple similar forms. To avoid writing same things many times, I've been trying to split the form template into another file. For some reason it doesn't render. I've tried to write it slightly different ways, but haven't found the right way yet.

Add.vue (page where I want to show the form)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <basicform/> 
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import basicform from './basicform.vue';

export default {
  name: "Add",
  components: {
     basicform
  },

};
</script>
```

basicform.vue

```
<template>
  <b-form @submit="submitForm" @reset="resetForm">
    <b-form-group label="Record name:">
      <b-form-input v-model="form.name"></b-form-input>
    </b-form-group>
    <b-form-group label="Year:">
      <b-form-input v-model="form.year"></b-form-input>
    </b-form-group>
    <b-form-group label="Artist:">
      <b-form-input v-model="form.artist"></b-form-input>
    </b-form-group>
    <b-button type="submit" variant="primary">Submit</b-button>
    <b-button type="reset" variant="danger">Reset</b-button>
  </b-form>
</template>

<script>
const basicform = {
  name: basicform,
  data: {
    form: {
      name: "",
      year: "",
      artist: ""
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submitForm(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      //Functionality for form post
    },
    resetForm(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      //functionality for form reset
    }
  }
};
export default basicform;
</script>
```

Comment: I suggest using `export default {...}` instead of `const basicform = {...}; export default basicform;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I fixed it. I had defined data wrong, this is the right way:

```
data () {
    return {
    form: {
      name: "",
      year: "",
      artist: ""
    }}
```

Thanks for answers anyway!

Answer (score 1):

The component name value should be a string `name: "basicform"` :

```
const basicform = {
  name: "basicform",
  data: {
    form: {
      name: "",
      year: "",
      artist: ""
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submitForm(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      //Functionality for form post
    },
    resetForm(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      //functionality for form reset
    }
  }
};
export default basicform;
```

This raises an error of

> basicform is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Render the component using `<basicform></basicform>` rather using the self terminating tag (`<basicform />`).